# Is Java's HttpServer asynchronous?

Tags: java

I would like to implement a lightweight HttpServer that can handle both GET and POST requests into a Bukkit plugin.

The current setup I have for my tiny web server creates an object extending `Thread`. It runs a small socket server on a new thread so that the web servers listening loop won't interfere with the main servers game servers operation.

I've come to the conclusion that Java's built-in `HttpServer` better suits my needs as I am trying to host a small website that needs to accept form data. However, after looking through a few websites and the documentation, I couldn't determine if Java's `HttpServer` already ran on a separate thread or not.

I wouldn't want to set up a new thread for this webserver where non is needed.

So, does Java's `HttpServer` run asynchronously or should I set up a new thread for it to run on?

Comment: From the docs, the start() method:
Starts this server in a new background thread.

Comment: @J11 - Thank you! Do you mind providing a link to the documentation you are referencing?

Comment: Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html

Comment: Does this means as well, that this http server can handle async calls from clients (Pipelining)?